# 2d data matrix(barcode) detection algorithm is not giving me results

Tags: barcode

I am working on detection of 2d data matrix but there is a problem in detection because barcode changes its design in each product so how to detect it? can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification of datamatrix is designed to be identified. You need to look at the code the way it is intended to be looked at. Where I'd start is that the code has a quiet zone and an "L" pattern. That is what you are looking for.

How you go about doing this depends a lot on the general parameters of the image.

The first consideration is lighting and contrast. Can you depend on having a fixed midpoint, where everthing lighter is called white and everything darker black? Or will a simple histogram give a usable midpoint? Or do shadows and uneven lighting cause a value to be called black on the sunny side of the image and the same tone white on the shadow side of an image? On a flatbed scanner it is easy to depend on good contrast, but camera phone photos are more problematic.

The next consideration is size and resolution. For a camera phone application, it is expected that in a low resolution image, a high percentage of the image will contain the barcode, while a scanner may have a lot of image and a little amount of barcode data which needs to be searched for.

Finally comes presentation. Will the barcode appear in 360 degrees of rotation? Will it be flat and level or can it be be skewed, curled and angled? Is there any concern about lens distortion?

Once you can answer the considerations, it should point to what you need to do to identify the barcode. Datamatrix has clocking marks which enable distorted codes to be read, but it is a lot more work to define distortion, so if it is not needed, you wouldn't do it.